What type of interior wall is this in my bathroom and how should i go about repairing it? I am a novice when when it comes to home repair


As stated in the title I'm a novice when it comes to home improvement. Unfortunately there are some cracks/holes in the bathroom as you can see in the photos and video. It isn't your typical drywall or anything and I'm unable to find it online. In addition, I have a interior/exterior hole repair kit but I'm not sure if it'll work for this (I'm a complete novice as stated in the title). What the exact wall type that I have and will a wall repair kit do the job for repairs? If it won't them what do you guys suggest?

Looks like hard plaster to me.  I imagine you could cut some more out with a knife to form larger areas to patch, while trying to match the texture.

Can you add a wider photo to show the wall? It could be a hard plaster wall on an older house (most likely), or a broken plastic wall, or a really dreadful mud job over drywall.

What country are you in and what year or decade or century was the house built?

I am located in the United states. As for a wider photo I am not sure as I took the photo this close on my phone to make sure it would fit the mb requirements for uploading photos via phone. I'm going with the hard plaster out of those possibilities.

That definitely looks like acrylic sheet. If you look at the cracked edge you can see how thin the material is. That pattern of cracks in the 2nd picture also looks like a flexible surface, not crumbly stuff held together with paper like drywall. Pic of whole wall would help a lot. If you can fit a strip of paper into the crack and move it around behind the wall, it's acrylic sheet. Don't know how to fix it, unfortunately; may not be possible.

That is textured drywall.  The crack is just hairline, but looks larger because the pic is so close. Usually that is the result of an impact, but could be from other things. These show up over a taped joint and could be from a heavy a layer of compound shrinking.
Normal repair is just filling with latex caulk and wiping with a damp sponge to force the caulk into the crack.  Wait a day to let it dry well and paint. Once painted the crack is unnoticeable.
If it comes back, you need to find the reason. It may be water intrusion, weakened wall studs, humidity buildup in the bathroom, or a number of other reasons.

Thanks, crossing my fingers that latex caulk will be enough.

You have might have drywall or one of those "insert" acrylic insert bath walls.
Test it with a pin. If you can push the pin it is drywall, if not it is acrylic.
You can try to glue (fill the crack) with some acrylic compound, but it will be visible.
If you just smear some drywall plaster over the crack, it will crack again.
I recommend using the fiberglass tape and then plaster over it..


I thought it looked like drywall with texture or plaster

Neither the textured surface nor jagged crack suggest acrylic to me. I'd expect an acrylic insert to be smooth and crack with a cleaner break.
